# How to update the splash screen loading message when the login window is on top of it

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I've a splash screen and a login window. When the application is opened, splash screen will be played first, and then the login window will be on top of the splash screen. The code below did fine for me:

App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) 
{
  splashScreen.Show();

  var startupTask = new Task(() => {
    //Set custom message on screen
    splashScreen.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => splashScreen.LoadingMsg = "Please wait..."));
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    splashScreen.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => splashScreen.LoadingMsg = "Please provide login information..."));
    Thread.Sleep(300);
  });

  //When loading finished, show login window
  startupTask.ContinueWith(t => {
    SPLogin loginWindow = new SPLogin();
    loginWindow.Owner = splashScreen;
    splashScreen.Cursor = Cursors.Wait; //???

    this.MainWindow = loginWindow;

    loginWindow.ShowDialog(); //Show the login window in modal mode
    splashScreen.Close();
  }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

  startupTask.Start();
}
```

So when I click the login button, suppose that the loading message should be updated at the splash screen when the login process is running, but my problem is the loading message will be updated after the login process is finished. Below is the code snippet on how I updating the loading message:

Login.cs:

```
  private void LoginProcess()
  {    
    App.splashScreen.LoadingMsg = "Connecting to Configuration Server..."; ///not update simultaneously

    //Login process........

    App.splashScreen.LoadingMsg = "Login successfully."; ///not update simultaneously
  }
```

Is there any suggestion on this?

Comment: is the login process (the area between "connecting.." and "login.." on a task?

Comment: Hi @d.moncada, technically yes, because when loginWindow.ShowDialog(). it runs Login.xaml.cs, when the login button is pressed (event in Login.xaml.cs), it linked to Login.cs

Comment: Is the LoginProcess method running on a different thread or anything?

Comment: Hi @User92, as what I've searched, if I want to update UI elements if the process is running on different thread, I need to do something like this:
App.splashScreen.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>            
{
                App.splashScreen.LoadingMsg = "Connecting to Configuration Server..."; ///not update simultaneously
            }));

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If it's on another thread, yes you do need to use the dispatcher, but that's not in your posted code above which is why I was asking. Also, if you use a BackgroundWorkerThread, you can set it to report progress, and the ReportProgress method will execute on the thread which spawned the worked thread, so the dispatcher won't be needed. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx for more info